# How do I browse a column of strings and convert any integers to the word in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, tokenize

I am creating a function that will go through a column of strings. In some of these strings there are numbers, and some strings there are not. If a string contains a number, I would like to change that number to the text version (i.e 'I was on hold for 20 minutes' to 'I was on hold for twenty minutes')

This is what I have so far, but I think the isdigit() is looking at the entire string instead of the tokens within the string.

```
import inflect

def int_to_word(words):
    p = inflect.engine()
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        if word.isdigit():
            new_word = p.number_to_words(word)
            new_words.append(new_word)
        else:
            new_words.append(word)
    return new_words
```

Comment: What is `words` input. Is it a list?

Comment: You've identified the problem; why haven't you tried to fix it?  Splitting a string into tokens is a well-documented process.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

This entirely depends on the input you're passing to `int_to_words` which you have not included in your question.

---

**Input: `string`**

You need to split your string into a list, which is split by spaces. This way you ensure that you're iterating over the entire number, and not the individual chars of the string.

```
def int_to_word(words):
    p = inflect.engine()
    new_words = []
    for word in words.split():
        if word.isdigit():
            new_words.append(p.number_to_words(word))
        else:
            new_words.append(word)
    return ' '.join(new_words)

print(int_to_word('I was on hold for 20 minutes'))
#I was on hold for twenty minutes
```

---

**Input: `list`**

With a list of sentences, you will need to add an extra iteration.

```
def int_to_word(words):
    p = inflect.engine()
    result = []
    for element in words:
        new_words = []
        for word in element.split():
            if word.isdigit():
                new_words.append(p.number_to_words(word)
                         )
            else:
                new_words.append(word)
        result.append(' '.join(new_words))
    return result
    
print(int_to_word(['I was on hold for 20 minutes', '1 2 3']))
#['I was on hold for twenty minutes', 'one two three']
```